# Error Running Frida : dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found

Tags: android, apk, frida

I got this error when running frida on certain android apps:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.plugins.deviceinfo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~I-ccvEdH_oqYw4q-eO6fQg==/com.dwidasa.bss.mb.android-qWOQ_CLOob_zVI3CAy7ngA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~I-ccvEdH_oqYw4q-eO6fQg==/com.someapps.apps.mb.android-qWOQ_CLOob_zVI3CAy7ngA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/env.js:124)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:443)
    at value (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:812)
    at _make (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:112)
    at use (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:63)
    at use (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:246)
    at <anonymous> (/bss_bypass.js:4)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:16)
    at _performPendingVmOps (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:238)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:230)
    at apply (native)
    at ne (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:613)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:592)
Process crashed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
```

frida version : 15.1.14 |
frida server : frida-server-15.1.14-android-x86|

I'm using Android Virtual Devices.

It works fine for other apps, but this target apps I currently working could only be running at aarch64/arm64. I dont know if its related to my error or not.

Comment: There are a few other questions here of SO with Frida problems when running an arm64 app in an x86 emulator. The emulator integrated translation subsystem doesn't seems to play well with Frida. If you want to run an arm64 app use an arm emulator or a real device.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestion for arm64 emulator? I'm using emulator from android visual studio.

Comment: Use Android Studio emulator and use an `arm64-v8a` image (see section `Other Images` when configuring the `System Image` in the `Virtual Device Configuration` dialog. Those native arm emulators should work but they will be pretty slow.